# General method to understand if a normal versor is ingoing or outgoing from a surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, surfaces

What is the easiest way to understand if the versor normal to a surface is outgoing or ingoing from the surface? (I need this in order to calculate fluxes)

So suppose to have the parametric surface $\mathrm{\bar{r}} : A \subset \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$
with $$\mathrm{\bar{r}}(x,y)=\big( \mathrm{r_1}(x,y), \mathrm{r_2}(x,y),\mathrm{r_3}(x,y) \big)$$

If I calculate the normal versor $\bar{\mathrm{n}}$ with the formula, then how to see if it is ingoing or outoging?

My guess would be to see the sign  of the dot product
$$\bar{\mathrm{n}} \cdot \mathrm{\bar{r}}$$
Since $\mathrm{\bar{r}}$ should be outgoing , therefore if $\bar{\mathrm{n}} \cdot \mathrm{\bar{r}}>0$ then $\bar{\mathrm{n}}$ is outgoing, otherwise ingoing.

Anyway I'm not sure about this. What is the general method to use?

Comment: If $\bar{r}$ defines a curve, say $C$ then the normal vector is prependicular to it and points in the direction which $T$ and so $C$ is turning.

Comment: Your idea of checking the sign of $\bar n \cdot \bar r$ only works under additional conditions, which could be, for example: $0$ is an interior point and the interior of the surface is convex.